# Pulling info from one class into another class

Tags: java, class

I am very new to Java.  For a class assignment, I need to input a sales person's name and annual sales, then display their total wages based on their fixed annual salary of $50,000. It has to include 2 classes.

I have the `salesperson` class working properly. The `Annualwages` class runs, but shows "hello null" and "your total annual compensation is $50,000" (which is just the fixed annual salary without added sales).

I cannot figure out how to pull info from `salesperson` when running `Annualwages`.

```
package annualwages;

import java.util.Scanner;

/** @author Rachael  */
class salesperson { //begins salesperson class
    int annualSales;
    String name;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int annualSales;
        String name;
        // Create a Scanner object to read input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in );

        //Get the user's name.
        System.out.print("What is your name? ");
        name = keyboard.nextLine();

        //Get the amount of annual Sales
        System.out.print("How much in sales did you make in the last year? ");
        annualSales = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

} //ends salesperson class
```

---

```
package annualwages;

/**
 *
 * @author Laptop
 */
public class Annualwages {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) { //begins the main method
        /**Declaration Statements */
        final double COMMISSION = 0.15;
        //Sets a fixed variable for commission earned

        final double SALARY = 50000;
        //Sets a fixed variable for Salary earned

        final double SALESTARGET = 120000;
        //Sets a fixed variable for the sales target

        double totalSales, totalWages, actualCommission, accelFactor = 1.25;
        /** 
         * initializes annual Sales, total Sales, Total Wages, 
         * actual commission and acceleration factor as a double. 
         * Sets the acceleration factor to increase by 1.25. */

        salesperson sp = new salesperson();

        //Sales incentive begins at a minimum at $96,000 in sales.
        //if less than, then no commission is earned
        if (sp.annualSales <= 96000) {
            actualCommission = 0;
        }

        // Sales incentive with $96,000 or more earns 15% commission
        else if ((sp.annualSales > 96000) && (sp.annualSales < SALESTARGET)) {
            actualCommission = COMMISSION;
        }

        //Sales incentive increases if the sales person earns more than $120,000
        //in sales with the acceleration factor of 1.25
        else {
            actualCommission = COMMISSION * accelFactor;
        }

        //Calculates total sales by multiplying sales and commission
        totalSales = sp.annualSales * actualCommission;

        //Calculates total wages by adding salary to total sales
        totalWages = SALARY + totalSales;

        //Display the resulting information.
        System.out.println("Hello " + sp.name);
        System.out.println("Your total annual compensation is $" + totalWages);
    } // ends main method

} // ends annual wages class
```

Comment: Try putting a encapsulating class around them. Then they can share.

Answer (score 1):

In your `salesperson` class, I would move all the code in your `main` function to a constructor. Something like what I have done below. Doing this allows you to set non-static fields so you can set your `name` and `annualSales` correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class salesperson {

    int annualSales;
    String name;

    public salesperson(){
        // Create a Scanner object to read input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Get the user's name.
        System.out.print("What is your name? ");
        name=keyboard.nextLine();

        //Get the amount of annual Sales
        System.out.print("How much in sales did you make in the last year? ");
        annualSales=keyboard.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Notice that I removed declaring `name` and `annualSales` from the method.
After this the rest of your code in your `Annualwages` class should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The two fields

```
 int annualSales;
 String name;
```

should be made "public static". Also you should not define them again in the main method.

Lastly it does not seem you are using an IDE. Download "Eclipse IDE" for writing code in Java. It will make your life much easier

Comment: Also, there are some compilation issues with your classes. Please correct that also before you run the code

Comment: Per the class instructions we have to use NetBeans. That is what I used to write this code. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like that:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 class salesperson {
 protected int annualSales;
 protected String name;

 public void saleInformation() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is your name? ");
    name = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("How much in sales did you make in the last year? ");
    annualSales = keyboard.nextInt();
}
}

public class Annualwages extends salesperson {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    salesperson s = new salesperson();
    s.saleInformation();

    final double COMMISSION = 0.15;
    final double SALARY = 50000;
    final double SALESTARGET = 120000;
    double totalSales, totalWages, actualCommission, accelFactor = 1.25;
    if (s.annualSales <= 96000) {
        actualCommission = 0;
    } else if ((s.annualSales > 96000) && (s.annualSales < SALESTARGET)) {
        actualCommission = COMMISSION;
    } else {
        actualCommission = COMMISSION * accelFactor;
    }
    totalSales = s.annualSales * actualCommission;
    totalWages = SALARY + totalSales;
    System.out.println("Hello " + s.name);
    System.out.println("Your total annual compensation is $" + totalWages);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped quite a bit!